# meaning of an expression in a sentence

Tags: expressions

what is the meaning of *so patent a manner* in the following sentence

Seeing him like this, dressed just for her **in so patent a manner**, she could not hold back the fiery blush that rose to her face.

Comment: Please check a dictionary first. If still in doubt try [ell.se] -- Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

One of the definitions of "[patent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patent)" is obvious or explicit.

> adj. Obvious; plain; apparent.

It was obvious to the girl that the man dressed just for her, so she blushed.

Comment: Hi, vf_s. Welcome to EL&U. Please add the definition - and a link is nice, too - when leaving an answer. It improves the quality of your answer, and makes it more authoritative. For suggestions on good answers, please visit the help center. Thanks.

Comment: And as you'll see from Kris's comment above, we prefer not to have people answering questions where the answer is so – er – obvious. The ELU site is not intended for basic questions. To keep it fair, we wouldn't expect questions like 'Is the intransitive preposition classification tenable' to be asked over on ELL.